# Dependent probabilities distributions?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

What's the best way to model situations with dependencies? What I mean is well-defined arrangements like:

> If I choose a 6-sided die with probability $p$ and a 20-sided one otherwise, and then roll it twice, what's the probability distribution on the sum of the two rolls?

Here's my current attempt:

```
p = 0.3
sides = TransformedDistribution[6+(1-d)*14, d \[Distributed]BernoulliDistribution[p]]    
rolls[dist_] := TransformedDistribution[x+y, {x,y} \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[{dist, 2}]]
sumDist = ParameterMixtureDistribution[rolls[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1,n}]], n \[Distributed] sides]
RandomVariate[sumDist, 10]
```

I get this formula for the random variate--it looks like $n$ isn't properly being passed through:

```
RandomVariate[
ParameterMixtureDistribution[
  TransformedDistribution[\[FormalX]1 + \[FormalX]2, {\[FormalX]1, \
\[FormalX]2} \[Distributed] 
    ProductDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, n}], 2}]], 
  n \[Distributed] 
   TransformedDistribution[
    6 + 14 (1 - \[FormalX]), \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
     BernoulliDistribution[0.3]]], 10]
```

My follow-on question will be to compute the probability of which die was chosen based on seeing a sum of e.g 11, so I'm trying to keep that initial choice in the model explicitly.

Comment: Hint: you're over-complicating this... step back and think about it.

Comment: `Conditioned[]` will be useful here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a start for you. *p* is probability of choosing die 1, f1/f2 are number of faces (starting at 1) for die 1/2:

```
p1 = 3/10
f1 = 6
f2 = 20
d = MixtureDistribution[{p1, 1 - p1}, {DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, f1}], 
                                       DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, f2}]}];

d2 = TransformedDistribution[a + b, {a, b} \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[{d, 2}]];

(* PMF of sums *)
Probability[x == #, x \[Distributed] d2] & /@ Range[2, 40] // Short

(* {289/40000,289/20000,867/40000,289/10000,<<32>>,147/40000,49/20000,49/40000} *)
```

You can also just use `PDF[d2,z]` to get PMF, will be slower...

Random variates from the distribution is just:

```
RandomVariate[d2,10]
(* {8, 25, 9, 22, 7, 20, 21, 15, 23, 20} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just building on @ciao (@rasher) to deal with second part:

```
c66 = TransformedDistribution[
   a + b, {a, b} \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}]];
p66 = Probability[x == 11, x \[Distributed] c66];
c620 = TransformedDistribution[
   a + b, {a, b} \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 20}}]];
p620 = Probability[x == 11, x \[Distributed] c620];
c2020 = TransformedDistribution[
   a + b, {a, b} \[Distributed] 
    DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 20}, {1, 20}}]];
p2020 = Probability[x == 11, x \[Distributed] c2020];
pdice[p_] := 
 With[{r = {p^2, 2 p (1 - p), (1 - p)^2} {p66, p620, p2020}}, {Total@
    r, r/Total@r}]
```

`pdice` will produce probability sum of pair of dice is 11 and the probability it came from {6,6}, {6,20}||{20,6}, {20,20} given total is 11 using $P(D={6,6}|Z=11)P(Z=11)=P(Z=11|D={6,6})P(D={6,6})$ etc.

So

```
Manipulate[
 PieChart[pdice[probability][[2]], 
  ChartLegends -> {"6-6", "6-20", "20-20"}, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
      Panel[NumberForm[#1, 2], FrameMargins -> 0], 
      "RadialCallout"] &)], {probability, 0, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

and "reality checking" cf @ciao:

```
pdice[3/10]
Probability[x == 11, x \[Distributed] d2]
```

yield:{153/4000, {20/153, 28/51, 49/153}} and 153/4000 respectively.

Comment: Oh, +1 on the cool-as-*$*% graphics manipulate... I always enjoy your examples!

Comment: @ciao thanks...could have done more tersely and general...alas lots to do :)